# Why doesn't yum-builddep install all dependencies?

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

What worked for other packages, doesn't work for kernel. Why?

First, sync:

```
[git@dioptase SRPMS]$ ssh root@localhost yum-builddep /home/git/rpmbuild/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.src.rpm
Getting requirements for kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.src
 --> Already installed : module-init-tools-3.9-21.el6_4.x86_64
 --> Already installed : patch-2.6-6.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : bash-4.1.2-15.el6_4.x86_64
 --> Already installed : coreutils-8.4-31.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : 2:tar-1.23-11.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : bzip2-1.0.5-7.el6_0.x86_64
 --> Already installed : 1:findutils-4.4.2-6.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : gzip-1.3.12-19.el6_4.x86_64
 --> Already installed : m4-1.4.13-5.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : 1:make-3.81-20.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : diffutils-2.8.1-28.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-42.el6.noarch
 --> Already installed : net-tools-1.60-110.el6_2.x86_64
 --> Already installed : patchutils-0.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : rpm-build-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : xmlto-0.0.23-3.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : asciidoc-8.4.5-4.1.el6.noarch
 --> Already installed : gnupg2-2.0.14-6.el6_4.x86_64
 --> Already installed : python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64
 --> Already installed : hmaccalc-0.9.12-1.el6.x86_64
No uninstalled build requires
```

Then build:

```
[git@dioptase SRPMS]$ rpmbuild --rebuild kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.src.rpm
Installing kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.src.rpm
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
error: Failed build dependencies:
        elfutils-libelf-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        elfutils-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        binutils-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        newt-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        python-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        audit-libs-devel is needed by kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: `mock` solves such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are arch dependent. Either rebuild the .src.rpm on the arch. you care about (the one in the source repos. is built on a random supported arch), or download and unpuck the .src.rpm and yum-buildep on the kernel.spec.